# Interrupt-On-Change during execution runtime

Tags: c, embedded, pic, interrupt-handling

I am using Interrupt-On-Change on RC7 of PIC16LF1618. Here is the initialization bit that I use for I-O-C:

```
void I_O_C_Initialize (void) {
    INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0;
    IOCCFbits.IOCCF7 = 0;
    INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;
    IOCCP = 0x80;
}
```

I am able to wake the PIC from a Power-Down Mode (SLEEP) using a positive trigger on RC7. However, I would like to have this trigger available during execution time as well, as if any positive trigger on RC7 should reset the PIC and go to the first line of the main() function.

Could you please let me know on how to achieve this?

P.S: Since the reset needs to happen as quick as possible and is crucial to the execution time, I am unable to add multiple if statements inside the main function to check for the positive trigger on RC7. Hence I am looking for an interrupt option to reset the PIC, even if it is executing a delay or function loops.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has now been resolved. After enabling GIE bit whenever I needed the Interrupt On Change (IOC) during runtime and using the below function, the IOC worked during runtime as well as Power-Down Mode (SLEEP).

```
void interrupt ISR (void);

void interrupt ISR (void) { 
    if (RC7==1) {
        asm("pagesel foobar");
        asm("goto foobar");
    }
    else
        return;
} 


asm("foobar:");
while (1) {
    IOCCFbits.IOCCF7 = 0;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;

    . //Do the calculations here
    . //Here if any Interrupt On Change happens for RC7,
    . //the ISR routine would stop all calculations and
    . //would return to the start of the loop without
    . //resetting any of the registers.

    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;
    IOCCFbits.IOCCF7 = 0;
    SLEEP();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most 8-bit PIC devices, and assuming you're using XC8, there is a definition that invokes the required assembly command:

```
#define RESET() asm("reset")
```

So, in your interrupt handler, just insert this line of code:

```
RESET();
```

Comment: Yes, I am using XC8. So, would something like this help?  

#define RESET() asm("reset")  

Inside the Main loop: //Since I am calling the SLEEP function, the GIE and PEIE bits should normally be disabled.  

 INTCONbits.GIE = 1;  
 INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;  

Before SLEEP function: //Disabling the the GIE and PEIE bits in order to wake up from SLEEP mode  

 INTCONbits.GIE = 0;  
 INTCONbits.PEIE = 0;  
void interrupt ISR (void) {  
    if (RC7 == 1) {  
 INTCONbits.GIE = 0;  
 INTCONbits.PEIE = 0;  
 IOCCF = ((IOCCF^0xFF)&IOCCF);  
 RESET();  
    }  
}

Comment: @ArunKumar It should already be defined, so just use `RESET();` wherever in your logic you need to - that logic is your choice, I just let you know how to force a hardware reset of the PIC from code. In your interrupt, you can check the relevant register to determine if you've just woken from sleep or not.

Comment: The RESET() works fine. However, it does a complete soft reboot and I would like to avoid that. Is there a way to jump to a label within the main() from the ISR interrupt?

Comment: You could possibly use a function pointer to jump to main in the ISR.

Comment: @KooroshHajiani No, not a good idea. Jumping out of an interrupt will leave the stack corrupt and cause problems later. Better to set a flag and catch it in the main loop.

Comment: @RogerRowland That's correct under normal interrupt processing however regarding this case Arun Kumar wants to hit the main from an ISR without a reset, how else is that possible?

Comment: @KooroshHajiani The correct design is to set a flag in the ISR and catch it from the main loop. The OP didn't show any of that logic so it's not clear why that's "not possible" but it's the right way to handle it. Jumping from the ISR leaves the system still logically inside the ISR with registers saved, global interrupts disabled, and an expectation of a `RETFIE` later, which will now never happen. It's absolutely *not* a solution to do that.

Comment: The main problem that I face is that if I use `RESET();` in the ISR, it takes around 420 us to do a reset and got to the top of the `main()`. Since I have to react as soon as I see an active high on RC7, I am unable to do so because the active high at RC7 changes within 8 us. Hence, I was looking for an ISR that could react as soon as an active high appears.

Comment: I could add multiple `if` statements to check if RC7 is high or not. But since there are a few SPI routines within the main function, which takes more than 15 us, this is not a feasible method.

Comment: @ArunKumar Why not simplify your main loop by using SPI via interrupts, then you have no need for "lengthy" routines. This is a common pattern.